# tengo problemas con el footer en bootstrap de mi pagina web

Tags: css, html5, web, bootstrap-5, footer

mi pregunta es realcionada con el footer en bootstrap , no encuentro la manera de que mi footer se quede abajo del todo en mi pagina web la cual por peticion de mi cliente no tiene mucho contenido en la pagina de inicio , ya he probado con las clases de bootstrap y tambien le he dado estilo al footer por separado en css. Como podria solucionar mi problema

Comment: Sin ver el código, es imposible ayudar. Muestra un [repro].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Con la clase `fixed-bottom` se logra eso.

```
<footer class="fixed-bottom">
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<p>Otras cosas</p>
<p>Otras cosas</p>
<p>Otras cosas</p>
<p>Otras cosas</p>
<p>Otras cosas</p>
<p>Otras cosas</p>
<p>Otras cosas</p>
<p>Otras cosas</p>
<p>Otras cosas</p>
<p>Otras cosas</p>
<p>Otras cosas</p>
<p>Otras cosas</p>
<div class="container my-1">

  <footer class="text-center text-lg-start fixed-bottom" style="background-color: #db6930;">
    <div class="container d-flex justify-content-center py-1">
      
    </div>

    <!-- Copyright -->
    <div class="text-center text-white p-1" style="background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);">
      © 2020 Copyright OCHOA
    </div>
    <!-- Copyright -->
  </footer>
  
</div>
<!-- End of .container -->
```

Comment: muchisimas gracias , pude resolver el problema gracias a usted ,

Comment: Me alegra. Para la próxima haz tu pregunta según [ask] para que no te la vayan a cerrar, porque poco faltó para que cerraran esta.

Comment: esta bien , gracias por prestarme un poco de su tiempo

Comment: Hola amigo , queria contactar con usted para hacerle una pregunta , puesto que el problema de mi footer se soluciono con el fixed , esta bien hasta ese momento , pero al hacer responsive a la pagina , el footer se queda en el final pero corta los demas elementos , lo que necesito exactamente es dejarlo al final del todo pero que no me interfiera en mis elementos al hacer responsive , puesto que no se puede leer bien el contenido , y visualmente queda mal , saludos de antemano